# Android emulator cannot connect with local tomcat server with HttpURLConeectioin

Tags: android, tomcat, httpurlconnection

I'm doing a project to connect Android with local Tomcat server. But now I'm facing a problem for about 1 week. Who can help me..Thanks very much!

I use the newest android API and Tomcat 7.0. When I start Tomcat server. I can access the Tomcat homepage through emulator browser with url:(http://10.0.2.2:8080). But when I use HttpUrlConnection in the code. I cannot get the successful connection. I also use httpurlconnection to access www.google.com and www.android.com. I cannot connect them either.I use HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK to see whether it make a successful connection. I also see the Connected is false for HttpURLConnection instance I make.

By the way I also add the internet access permission for it in AndroidManifest.xml before tag.

Thank you very much! Help me. It's emergency.

Comment: You might want to add some code to your question, so people can check whether it right or wrong.

Comment: what  is the logcat output ?

Comment: Thanks,I use wireshark to capture, but when I try my own program on android. It cannot get anything. I am very new with tomcat and android, so I just think this is an very easy problem.I just think may be some configuration I forget or make a mistake. So HttpURLconnection doesn't work

Comment: I just write URL url=new URL("https://10.0.2.2:8080"); HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Comment: there is a https:// before 10.0.2.2:8080

Comment: so try it with an httpsurlconnection...

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem.  As mentioned above, (on Windows) start cmd, and use ipconfig to find the PC's IP address.  Also, due to my Eclipse/Tomcat configuration I needed to have my Eclipse project name in the URL.  The URL I used was like this:  http://192.168.1.2/myEclipseProject/ServletName

Also, you may need to add the port to the ip address, if your Tomcat still has the default configuration:  192.168.1.2:8080